# WM_TOUCH event not received anymore after screen disconnection

Tags: c#, winapi, touch, pinvoke, setwindowshookex

I have a C# application handling touch by hooking to the Windows API message loop and listening to `WM_TOUCH` event.

It work perfectly except when the screen is disconnected or switch off. Windows OS still has touch but the application don't receive touch event anymore.

Here the code used.
On application start, I use [RegisterTouchWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registertouchwindow) to register for `WM_TOUCH` events. I use [RegisterDeviceNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerdevicenotificationa)  to watch devices changes.
On devices changes, `IsTouchEnabled` check the state of touch with `GetSystemMetrics(SM_DIGITIZER)`. if touch is not available and it was registered previously with `RegisterTouchWindow`, I unregister it with  [UnregisterTouchWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-unregistertouchwindow).

if it is available and has not been registered or has been unregistered, it register with [RegisterTouchWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registertouchwindow). This is were it fail. `RegisterTouchWindow` return true but the `WndProc` will not received any `WM_TOUCH` event.

I tried to not Unregister touch when device is lost but it is the same result.

I checked the messages with Spy++. after the touch has been disconnected then recconected, there is no `WM_TOUCH` message appearing in spy++.

Here you can download the source code of a WPF test application to reproduce the problem https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E-RdiHAH0mfIEFj1-hNaBzVCfhn1iaNp/view?usp=sharing

```cs
public static bool IsTouchEnabled() {
 var value = (SM_DIGITIZER_FLAG) GetSystemMetrics(SM_DIGITIZER);
 return value.HasFlag(SM_DIGITIZER_FLAG.NID_EXTERNAL_TOUCH) ||
  value.HasFlag(SM_DIGITIZER_FLAG.NID_INTEGRATED_TOUCH) ||
  value.HasFlag(SM_DIGITIZER_FLAG.NID_EXTERNAL_PEN) ||
  value.HasFlag(SM_DIGITIZER_FLAG.NID_INTEGRATED_PEN);
}

public static void RegisterUsbDeviceNotification(IntPtr windowHandle) {
 DevBroadcastDeviceinterface dbi = new DevBroadcastDeviceinterface {
  DeviceType = DbtDevtypDeviceinterface,
   Reserved = 0,
   ClassGuid = GuidDevinterfaceUSBDevice,
   Name = 0
 };

 dbi.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(dbi);
 IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(dbi.Size);
 Marshal.StructureToPtr(dbi, buffer, true);

 notificationHandle = RegisterDeviceNotification(windowHandle, buffer, 0);
}

protected void OnSourceInitialized(object o, EventArgs e) {
 var source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(win) as HwndSource;

 RegisterUsbDeviceNotification(source.Handle);

 RegisterTouchEvent(source.Handle);

 //setup windows hook here
 source.AddHook(WndProc);
}

private bool RegisterTouchEvent(IntPtr handle) {
 if (!IsTouchEnabled()) {
  logger.Warn("no Touch device available");
  if (_touchRegistered) {
   if (!UnregisterTouchWindow(handle))
    logger.Info("problem during touch unregistering");
   _touchRegistered = false;
   logger.Info("unregister touch event");
  }
  OnTouchNotAvailable();
  return false;
 }
 if (_touchRegistered)
  return true;

 if (!RegisterTouchWindow(handle, RegisterTouchFlags.TWF_WANTPALM)) {
  var err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
  logger.Error("cant register touch window. error " + err);
  return false;
 } else
  logger.Info("Win Touch source initialysed");
 _touchRegistered = true;

 return true;
}

private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref Boolean handled) {
 if (msg == WmDevicechange) {

  WmDevicechangeParam p = (WmDevicechangeParam) wParam.ToInt32();
  logger.Info("Device changed -> " + p.ToString());
  var source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(win) as HwndSource;
  if (source != null)
   RegisterTouchEvent(source.Handle);
  return new IntPtr(1);
 }

 if (msg == WM_TOUCH) {
  handled = HandleTouch(wParam, lParam);
  return new IntPtr(1);
 }

 return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Here the log I get when I switch off the touch screen and switch it on again

```
Win Touch source initialysed
//Screen switched off ----------------------
Device changed -> DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE
no Touch device available
unregister touch event
Device changed -> DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED
no Touch device available
Device changed -> DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED
no Touch device available
Device changed -> DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED
no Touch device available
//Screen switched on ----------------------
Device changed -> DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED
no Touch device available
Device changed -> DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED
no Touch device available
Device changed -> DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED
no Touch device available
Device changed -> DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED
no Touch device available
Device changed -> DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL
no Touch device available
Device changed -> DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED
Win Touch source initialysed
Device changed -> DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED
```

Here all the PInvoke function and WinApi enum used

```cs
private static readonly Int32 WM_TOUCH = 0x0240;

public enum WmDevicechangeParam {
 DBT_CONFIGCHANGECANCELED = 0x0019,
  DBT_CONFIGCHANGED = 0x0018,
  DBT_CUSTOMEVENT = 0x8006,
  DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000,
  DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE = 0x8001,
  DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVEFAILED = 0x8002,
  DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = 0x8004,
  DBT_DEVICEREMOVEPENDING = 0x8003,
  DBT_DEVICETYPESPECIFIC = 0x8005,
  DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED = 0x0007,
  DBT_QUERYCHANGECONFIG = 0x0017,
  DBT_USERDEFINED = 0xFFFF,
}

// device is gone
public
const int WmDevicechange = 0x0219;

// device change event
private
const int DbtDevtypDeviceinterface = 5;

private
const int MAXTOUCHES_INDEX = 0x95;
private
const int SM_DIGITIZER = 94;
private
const uint WM_DISPLAYCHANGE = 0x007e;
private static readonly Guid GuidDevinterfaceUSBDevice = new Guid("A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED");
private static readonly Int32 touchInputSize = Marshal.SizeOf(new TOUCHINPUT());

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern uint GetLastError();

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int nIndex);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool RegisterTouchWindow(IntPtr hwnd,
 [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] RegisterTouchFlags flags);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool UnregisterTouchWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32")]
[
 return :MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)
]
private static extern void CloseTouchInputHandle(IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32")]
[
 return :MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)
]
private static extern Boolean GetTouchInputInfo(IntPtr hTouchInput, Int32 cInputs, [In, Out] TOUCHINPUT[] pInputs, Int32 cbSize);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr RegisterDeviceNotification(IntPtr recipient, IntPtr notificationFilter, int flags);

// USB devices
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool UnregisterDeviceNotification(IntPtr handle);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct DevBroadcastDeviceinterface {
 internal int Size;
 internal int DeviceType;
 internal int Reserved;
 internal Guid ClassGuid;
 internal short Name;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct TOUCHINPUT {
 public Int32 x;
 public Int32 y;
 public IntPtr hSource;
 public Int32 dwID;
 public Int32 dwFlags;
 public Int32 dwMask;
 public Int32 dwTime;
 public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
 public Int32 cxContact;
 public Int32 cyContact;
}

public enum DWFlags {
 TOUCHEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001,

  TOUCHEVENTF_DOWN = 0x0002,

  TOUCHEVENTF_UP = 0x0004,
}

[Flags, Serializable]
public enum RegisterTouchFlags {
 TWF_NONE = 0x00000000,

  TWF_FINETOUCH = 0x00000001,

  TWF_WANTPALM = 0x00000002
}

[Flags]
public enum SM_DIGITIZER_FLAG {
 TABLET_CONFIG_NONE = 0x00000000, //    The input digitizer does not have touch capabilities.
  NID_INTEGRATED_TOUCH = 0x00000001, // An integrated touch digitizer is used for input.
  NID_EXTERNAL_TOUCH = 0x00000002, //   An external touch digitizer is used for input.
  NID_INTEGRATED_PEN = 0x00000004, //   An integrated pen digitizer is used for input.
  NID_EXTERNAL_PEN = 0x00000008, // An external pen digitizer is used for input.
  NID_MULTI_INPUT = 0x00000040, //  An input digitizer with support for multiple inputs is used for input.
  NID_READY = 0x00000080, //The input digitizer is ready for input. If this value is unset, it may mean that the tablet service is stopped, the digitizer is not supported, or digitizer drivers have not been installed.
}

private struct TouchMessage
{
    public int Count
    { get; private set; }

    public TOUCHINPUT[] inputs
    { get; private set; }

    public TouchMessage(TOUCHINPUT[] inputs, int count)
        : this()
    {
       this.inputs = inputs;
       this.Count = count;
    }
}

private static Int32 LoWord(Int32 number)
{
    return number & 0xffff;
}
```

Comment: A tip for your `WndProc`: if you didn't handle the message, let `DefWindowProc` handle it instead of `return IntPtr.Zero;`. Refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/getting-started-with-multi-touch-messages) for how to handle Windows Touch Messages.

Comment: And what's your application type? A mini, complete and reproducible code sample is helpful for other people to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Please fix the typo. `VW_TOUCH` is not a well-known symbolic constant in Windows.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I modified `WndProc` according to the documentation you sent.

I return `DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam)` if I am not interested in the message and I return  `new IntPtr(0);` if I am interested.

But when I do this, I only receive Down event and it change nothing on screen disconnection.

My application is a WPF application. I will try to upload a testable code sample

Comment: I uploaded a simple solution which display a windows and output to the console when a touch event is received in the window.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E-RdiHAH0mfIEFj1-hNaBzVCfhn1iaNp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Just do a quick test on the surface book, the demo works well for me. What's device you are testing?

Comment: @FeiXue I made a mistake in the description. It work when computer go in sleep mode.
The problem occurs when an external touch screen is switch off or disconnected. On reconection, windows get touch back but not the application. You won't be able to test it with an integrated touch screen.

Comment: Did that mean if you restart the application after re-connect/switch on the touch again, the application also could work well?

Comment: Yes the application work well if it is restarted after screen disconnection.

Comment: @Gael Would you mind also checking this message using Spy++ to see if this issue is relative to the HwndSource.AddHook?

Comment: @FeiXue I checked with spy++. before disconnection I see `WM_TOUCH` messages in spy++. after disconnection/reconnection I don't see any.